# How do I remove messages that sometimes keep showing up in the Flagged-folder in Mail although they are unflagged?

Tags: mail.app

(With Gmail-Accounts?) sometimes emails that were unflagged erroneously keep showing up in the Flagged-folder of Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is moving the messages to Trash manually. Afterwards move them to the Inbox again.